# android : how to make this circle imageveiw ?? (example)

Tags: android, layout

I saw how to do it on Squares layout, but does not work as circles.. sorry for my English

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think view can't be circle (i mean: has width and height, it's rectangle). If you want just circle imageView, seaech for library called CircleImageView by hdodenhof.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a circle,you can rewrite the imageView

public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

```
private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 1;

private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;

private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();

private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
private int mBitmapWidth;
private int mBitmapHeight;

private float mDrawableRadius;
private float mBorderRadius;

private boolean mReady;
private boolean mSetupPending;

public CircleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);

    a.recycle();

    mReady = true;

    if (mSetupPending) {
        setup();
        mSetupPending = false;
    }
}

@Override
public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return SCALE_TYPE;
}

@Override
public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (getDrawable() == null) {
        return;
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    setup();
}

public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
    if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderColor = borderColor;
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    invalidate();
}

public int getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    mBitmap = bm;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
    setup();
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private void setup() {
    if (!mReady) {
        mSetupPending = true;
        return;
    }

    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

    mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

    mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

    mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2);

    mDrawableRect.set(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth, mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth);
    mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2, mDrawableRect.width() / 2);

    updateShaderMatrix();
    invalidate();
}

private void updateShaderMatrix() {
    float scale;
    float dx = 0;
    float dy = 0;

    mShaderMatrix.set(null);

    if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
        scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
        dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
    } else {
        scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
        dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
    }

    mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mBorderWidth);

    mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5303) is a perfect solution for you. But may be you will not like this for giving an extra image for shape. But I think by using this lib you will get a solution for all types of shape. Just you need to give an image for exact shape (say, you put an image with triangle shape, than your image on image view will be like this). Here is another thing, If you want to use this lib you have to go with ImageView.